# Что за член предложения и выделяется ли он запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, члены-предложения, обстоятельство

"На улицу, из отделения, выходить в сменной обуви".
"Из отделения" – это обстоятельство места? И нужны ли здесь запятые?

Comment: Денис, скажите, пожалуйста, это полное предложение? Как его понимать? Пришёл, переобулся в сменку, и в ней же выходить на улицу?

Comment: Да, полное. Только не смейтесь и не ругайтесь, предложение увидел на объявлении в больнице и показалось, что запятые лишние, решил уточнить у специалистов )

Comment: Денис, абсолютно нет никаких подколов и пр. Хорошо, что спросили. Ладно запятые... Но что это вообще? Как такое может быть, кто до такого додумался?! :)) Может, всё-таки не дописали "запрещено"?

Comment: Забыл уточнить совсем :) , имеется в виду, что "больные, которые лежат в отделении и хотят выйти на улицу, до выхода на улицу должны переобуться в сменную обувь(сменить тапки на уличную обувь)".

Comment: Обычно сменной обувью называют чистую. Даже в словаре это есть: [сменная обувь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/сменная_обувь).

Comment: Этого не знал, всегда думал, что сменная обувь - это просто обувь на замену, запас) спасибо, буду знать )

Comment: Да, сменная подразумевается не уличная, но может быть у них все наоборот, в больнице обувь больничная, а на улице сменная?

Answer (score 1):

*На улицу, **из отделения**, выходить в сменной обуви*.

**Пояснение.** Больные, которые лежат в отделении и хотят выйти на улицу, до выхода на улицу должны переобуться в сменную обувь(сменить тапки на уличную обувь).

Все логично и правильно. **Сменная обувь** в прямом значении —  это обувь, которую нужно **сменить**. Если в отделении человек ходит в тапках, то на улицу нужно надеть кроссовки/ботинки, или наоборот.

Обстоятельство места обособили в качестве **дополнительного сообщения**, чтобы понятно было, о чем речь. Стиль свободный)

**Можно так написать**: *Просьба при выходе из отделения на улицу надеть сменную обувь.*

Comment: УжОс! Поощряете всякую всячину! // С запятыми согласен. // Вопрос отплюсовать не мешало бы. // В больнице по таким моментам должна быть не просьба, а требование.

Comment: Вы бы, наверное, и Достоевскому написали бы: "УжОс! О чем вы пишете!"  //  Не просьба, а требование, да? Особая строгость по отношению к бедным больным людям?

Comment: Вот именно, по отношению к больным людям. Они и так хворают, а мы такие "милосердные", что не запрещаем, а просим не распространять заразу.

Comment: Не в этом дело. Они тапки на улице грязью заляпают, а потом обратно в больничку.

Comment: Ну так об этом и речь. Должен быть строгий контроль: спустился, переобулся, вышел... зашёл, переобулся, пошёл в палату. // Sharon, я не злобничаю, правда (сегодня от меня вы получили 8 плюсов).

Comment: *Надеть уличную обувь

Comment: Слово "сменный" в прямом значении здесь не канает. Сменка в школе – это лёгкая чистая обувь, которую надевают (набувают :)) после улицы, а не наоборот.

Comment: Ух, даже не ожидал такой активности, спасибо всем за помощь, не могу только разобраться, как ставить плюсы, но всем как минимум душевный лайк :)

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, второй голос от меня.  Задавайте еще вопросы и приходите к нам (решать задачи).